# play framework sbt compiling indefinetly sometimes

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm using play framework 2.8.16 running Java 1.8.0_281. Sbt version is  1.7.1

Sometimes when i build the image in jenkins, the compilation runs indefinitely. This happens due to a particular commit. But i don't see any issue in the commit, as it compiles most of the times. Below are the logs.

```
[info] Wrote /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/hvh-user-service_2.13-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 9 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] done compiling
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 23 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/controllers/web/WebWorkflowController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/controllers/web/WebWorkflowController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/services/WorkflowService.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/services/WorkflowService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] done compiling
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 9 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] done compiling
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 23 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/controllers/web/WebWorkflowController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/controllers/web/WebWorkflowController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/services/WorkflowService.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/services/WorkflowService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] done compiling
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 9 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] done compiling
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 23 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/controllers/web/WebWorkflowController.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/controllers/web/WebWorkflowController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/services/WorkflowService.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/services/WorkflowService.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] done compiling
[info] compiling 1 Scala source and 9 Java sources to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[info] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/hvh_user-service/app/com/company/utils/Utils.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: Could you add more details about your issue? you mentioned a particular commit, what kind of changes you introduced there? what's the command executed in jenkins when you see the compilation running indefinitely? is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?